# Crystal Reports is cutting right text on report and paper

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I got this problem that drive me crazy. I have a project in VS2013 with v.13.0.15.1840. I'm using a auto grow field (has his own section) in crystal reports that is displaying a text interpreted as RTF. The problem is that on preview and even paper, the right side of the text is cut off (see screenshot). If the text is justified the it shows OK but I have situations when I need the text align to left.

So far I tried but with no effect:

- Setting margins manually on Format Object, Paragraph.
- Selecting no printer,Disassociating formatting page size and printer paper size.
- Making the field smaller horizontally.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

[image: result of text cutting]

The field on designer:
[image: the field on the designer]

**Edited for further explanations:**

The RTF code can be viewed at  https://gist.github.com/andySF/7ca61ffbe6ab6da53ca1

Also another try was to put my field in a textbox and then setting the right margin of the textbox to 3cm. It appears that the margin is somehow overridden after the first paragraph.

[image: field in textbox with 3cm right margin]

Comment: you need to fit the field exactly to the length of design of the report else your data will be cut off

Comment: If you mean like this then there is no effect. http://screencast.com/t/7Cfg0vAq22u

Comment: I can't open that image..its blocked can you post in your question itself

Comment: done. Is at the bottom of the post

Comment: yes... exactly as the image.... it doesn't make any difference if you add the field directly or in a text or in formula field... margins shouldn't be execeded.

Comment: As you can see it's not working but I figured out a solution that implies editing the \ri code in RTF. I'l test it and post a possible answer if everything is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Use
Modyfi your datasource text rtf before send in to report CR

```
model.Document= model.Document.Replace("\pard", "\pard\ri380")
```

Comment: tried on the example from the post (https://gist.github.com/andySF/7ca61ffbe6ab6da53ca1) but there is no difference.